# Tidy.Net Parsing Issue

Tags: core-service, xml

While I am trying to create few components through Core service, to form XHTML we're using Tidy.net, but I found some  dispensary in tidy.net. After parsing the content I see some additional "\r\n"added to the content as below

Original Content

[image]

After  Parsing through Tidy.net
[image: After Parsing through Tidy.net]

My code as follows

```
MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source));
            MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();

            TidyMessageCollection tmc = new TidyMessageCollection();
            Tidy tidy = new Tidy();


            tidy.Options.DocType = DocType.Omit;
            tidy.Options.DropFontTags = true;
            tidy.Options.LogicalEmphasis = true;
            tidy.Options.Xhtml = true;
            tidy.Options.XmlOut = true;
            tidy.Options.MakeClean = true;
            tidy.Options.TidyMark = false;
            tidy.Options.NumEntities = true;

            tidy.Parse(input, output, tmc);
```

Do we have any options with Tidy.net to avoid this additional Carriage return?
Did anyone have handled this before?

Comment: Is there a `tidy.Options.Wrap` or similar? If this is an implementation of HTML Tidy, I believe it will wrap lines at around  68 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tidy.Options.WrapLen` this resolved my problem

Comment: I think you should ask Dave Forber to make an answer with his comment since it helped you resolve your issue :)